# How to use MessageEntity in the SendMessage

Tags: java, telegram-bot

How to use correctly MessageEntity to get url that will be opened after user taps on the text?
This code sends only "Some text" to the chart. What's wrong? Where is the clickable text "Link" in the message?
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLpL8.gif)

```java
   MessageEntity messageEntity = new MessageEntity();
   messageEntity.setType("text_link");
   messageEntity.setUrl("https://google.com");
   messageEntity.setText("Link");
   messageEntity.setOffset(0);
   messageEntity.setLength(0);

   List<MessageEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
   entities.add(messageEntity);

   SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
   message.setChatId(String.valueOf(textChat_id));
   message.setEntities(entities);
   message.setText("Some text");
                
   try {
     execute(message);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

**UPD.** I've solved it.

- "messageEntity.setText("Link")" is redundant here,
- "message.setText("Link")" rewrote text "Some text" -> "Link",
- setOffset(0) - is start of the entity("Link"),
- setLength(4) - is length of the entity ("Link").

```java
   MessageEntity messageEntity = new MessageEntity();
   messageEntity.setType("text_link");
   messageEntity.setUrl("https://google.com");
   //messageEntity.setText("Link");
   messageEntity.setOffset(0);
   messageEntity.setLength(4);

   List<MessageEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
   entities.add(messageEntity);

   SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
   message.setChatId(String.valueOf(textChat_id));
   message.setEntities(entities);
   message.setText("Link");
   try {
     execute(message);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: See [formatting-options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) . Use `parse_mode = HTML` and send anchor tag as text in `sendMessage` method